# Rails 5 - can't destroy an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to delete an event in my app:

```
   def destroy
     @event.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

(there is `set_event` method as a `before_action` before `destroy`)

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td>Due date:</td>  <%= event.date %><br>
    <td>City:</td>  <%= event.city %><br>
    <td>Address:</td    >   <%= event.address %><br>
    <td>Time:</td   >   <%= event.time %><br>
    <td>Capacity:</td>  <%= event.capacity %><br>
    <td>Fee:</td>   <%= event.fee %><br>
    <%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Delete", event, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Clicking on "Delete", brings me to my event_path, e.g. http://localhost:3000/events/1. It doesn't destroy the item. I read it can be something with JS but I have all gems and my application.js looks fine. I'm using Rails 5.0

Comment: are you working on a Windows system ?

Comment: yes, can it be an issue?

Comment: yes, this one of the famous issue that **Windows users** come across! What actually happens is you do not have `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` in your layout `application.html.erb`. Ideally `//= require jquery_ujs` is required in `application.js` which indeed helps to identify whether a request is `get` or `delete`.

So, as you would have changed `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` to `<%= javascript_include_tag :default %>`, so `jquery_ujs` does not work! So,`delete` request is accepted as a `get` request & controller maps it to `show` action instead of `destroy`.

Comment: Indeed, I've changed "application" to "default" a while ago. Is there any way to make it work or I have to switch to Linux?

Comment: I would highly recommend you to move to Linux or else just for learning purpose you can always use https://c9.io/ .

Comment: I have extended the cause of problem as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the famous issue that **Windows users** come across!

What actually happens is you do not have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

in your layout `application.html.erb`

Ideally `//= require jquery_ujs` is required in `application.js` which indeed helps to identify whether a request is `get` or `delete` or `put`.

As you would have changed

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :default %>
```

so **`jquery_ujs`** does not work!

So, `delete` request is accepted as a `get` request & controller maps it to `show` action instead of `destroy` action.

Answer (score 1):

`confirm` should be in `data` attribute value hash, try this

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', event_path(event), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete %>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look your routes that delete method always carries object_id

You can try both ways:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', event_path(event.id), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', event_path(event), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete %>
```